# usage of extended true in body parser?

Tags: body-parser

please reveal me the difference between extended true and extended false in urlencoded bodyparser, some tutorials use extended true while other uses extended false, I'm very confused in between these two boolean expressions

Answer (score 0):

The extended option allows to choose between parsing the URL-encoded data with the querystring library (when false ) or the qs library (when true ). The “extended” syntax allows for rich objects and arrays to be encoded into the URL-encoded format, allowing for a JSON-like experience with URL-encoded.